# Include js file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, include, external-js

At first, sorry for my english))

i need include a file in nodejs file.

this is my file:

```
......    
var db_tools=require('./node/db_tools.js');
db_tools.some_fnc(some_data);
......
```

and this is my include file:

```
function some_fnc(some_data){
console.log(some_date);
}
```

and i have a error:

```
has no method 'some_fnc'
```

Please help me for include the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export something from there. in your file try

```
exports.some_fnc = function some_fnc(some_data){
  console.log(some_date);
}
```